# How to create AWS spot instances with Kops or Kubernetes?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kops

I am currently using kops to create AWS EC2 clusters. But it does not seem to have an option to specify 'spot' instances.

Does anybody know how to create instances of type 'spot' with kops or with kubernetes?

Answer (score 4):

From the docs
https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/blob/master/docs/instance_groups.md#converting-an-instance-group-to-use-spot-instances

> Follow the normal procedure for reconfiguring an InstanceGroup, but
>   set the maxPrice property to your bid. For example, "0.10" represents
>   a spot-price bid of $0.10 (10 cents) per hour.

So after `kops create cluster` but before `kops update cluster --yes` run `kops edit ig nodes --name $NAME` and set maxPrice to your max bid.

```
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2016-07-10T15:47:14Z"
  name: nodes
spec:
  machineType: t2.medium
  maxPrice: "0.01"
  maxSize: 3
  minSize: 3
  role: Node
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that [gardener/machine-controller-manager](https://github.com/gardener/machine-controller-manager/blob/17181f6b/pkg/driver/driver_aws.go#L107) could be taught about Spot instances fairly easily, and there is [an existing issue](https://github.com/gardener/machine-controller-manager/issues/27) to do just such a thing. I can't recall off-hand if that is *the* Node Controller Manager that I recalled seeing, or it is merely *a* Node Controller Manager and thus there may be other implementations of that idea which already include spot support.

That makes a presumption that you actually meant spot for the *workers*, and not for the whole cluster. If you mean the whole cluster, then you may be much, much happier with something like [kubespray](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/kubespray#readme) and use that to lay a functioning cluster on top of existing machines. Just bear in mind that while kubernetes *certainly is* resilient to "damage," including the loss of a master, an etcd member, and without question the loss of a `Node`, it might frown if a huge portion of its machines vanish at once. In other words: using spot *could* mean that you spend more programmer/devops/glucose triaging spot disappearance, or you have to so vastly overprovision replicas that it starts to eat into the savings from spot in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I need to be able to create atleast 1 node as "AWS EC2 OnDemand" instance and the rest of the nodes as "AWS EC2 Spot" instance. Do you know if "Kubespray" would allow this?

Comment: So the short version is yes, but the asterisk is that kubespray does not, itself, _provision_ machines. It merely configures otherwise blank machines as a cluster master, a cluster member, an etcd member, vault, or any combination of those that you wish. That's explicitly why I started the discussion with the Node Controller Manager, so the cluster could add more Nodes to _itself_. That project is certainly not the only way -- even using `awscli` with the right user-data could do the job just fine